# Passing Integer and Object value in Intent not working

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android project and just faced a little issue. After banging hours on it, I am really helpless. I am putting my code and a short description straight away to just to get you know what I am doing.

**What I am doing:** 
I have a child fragment that is opening an activity for result and setting some extras like so

```
            Intent intentDialogChangeStore = new Intent(getActivity(), FindStoreActivity.class);
            intentDialogChangeStore.putExtra("POSITION_CLICKED", position);
            intentDialogChangeStore.putExtra("POSITION_NAME", "NAME");
            startActivityForResult(intentDialogChangeStore, FindStoreActivity.RC_CHANGE_STORE);
```

and setting result from opened activity like so

```
            Intent returningIntent = new Intent();
            returningIntent.putExtra("MODEL_SELECTED",myModel);
            returningIntent.putExtra("POSITION_CLICKED",position);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returningIntent);


            this.finish();
```

and in my fragment I am catching it like this

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode == FindStoreActivity.RC_CHANGE_STORE) {

        if (data != null) {

            if (data.hasExtra("MODEL_SELECTED")) {
                MyCustomModel newSelectedModel = 
                 data.getParcelableExtra("MODEL_SELECTED");

                int position = data.getIntExtra("POSITION_CLICKED", -1);

                if (position == -1) {
                    return;
                }}}}
```

**ISSUE:** I am not getting any value against key `POSITION_CLICKED`, however I am getting object of `MyCustomModel` which is my model that I have sent against `MODEL_SELECTED` key.

But when I send my position only I get it in `OnActivityResult`. However whenever I send my Parcelable object, I never get anything against `POSITION_CLICKED` which is a simple integer value.

Is this a bug? I have tested on different systems and different devices but no luck. Please let me know what I am  doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,You see **" "POSITION_CLICKED" "** before setResult() method. You put quotes two times .Correct is **"POSITION_CLICKED"**.

Comment: yes that was typo error while posting question here. In code I have checked each and everything. Still there is issue, YES!!!

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("POSITION_CLICKED", position);
intent.putExtras(bundle);    try it

Comment: and for get value. Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int position= bundle.getInt("POSITION_CLICKED",-1);

Comment: You can add your parrcel bal value  like this.;
        bundle.putParcelable("MODEL_SELECTED",myModel);

Comment: I have done this also before posting question but no luck